# scala : continue processing on exception

Tags: scala, exception

I am new to scala and have a requirement where i have to continue processing the next records when an exception arises.

```
 object test {

      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        try {
          val txt = Array("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")
          val arr_val = txt(3)
          println(arr_val)
          val arr_val1 = txt(0)
          println(arr_val1)            
scala.util.control.Exception.ignoring(classOf[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException]) {
        println { "Index ouf of Bounds" }
      }
        } catch {
          case ex: NullPointerException =>
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried ignoring the exception , but the value of `arr_val1` is not getting printed because of the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException which arises ahead of this line.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scala.util.Try`can be used to capture the value of a computation that may contain a value or throw an exception. So, in your example `txt(0)` should contain the value "ABC" and `txt(3)` will thrown an exception. In each case you want to print out something different.

Here's a similar example to iterate through some made up indices in a `List` and try to access that index in `txt`. Some of these will result in a value and some will fail. In both cases that result is captured in the `Try` as a `Success` or `Failure`. Based on which type is returned a message is printed similar to your example.

```
scala> List(0,1,3,2,4,5).foreach(x => println(Try(txt(x)).getOrElse(println("Index ouf of bounds"))))
ABC
DEF
Index ouf of bounds
()
GHI
Index ouf of bounds
()
Index ouf of bounds
()
```